# Kernel and rank of sum of finite linear operators

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How do you think this excercise can be done?

Let $U,V$ finite dimensional vector spaces and $A,B:U\to V$ linear transformations. Then $$\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Ker}(A+B))\le\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Ker}(A)\cap\mathrm{Ker}(B))+\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{Ran}(A)\cap\mathrm{Ran}(B))$$

I know that $\mathrm{Ker}(A)\cap\mathrm{Ker}(B)\subseteq\mathrm{Ker}(A+B)$, so i was thinking take a basis for $\mathrm{Ker}(A)\cap\mathrm{Ker}(B)$ and extend it to a basis for $\mathrm{Ker}(A+B)$ and extend it to a basis for $U$, but i don't get a good approach.

Comment: Do you know about quotient spaces?

Comment: Yes, but I can't use it directly (indeed the hint is use $A|_{ker(A+B)}$.

Comment: By the way, you can use the shortcut `\ker` instead of `\mathrm{ker}`

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $x \in \ker(A + B)$ (i.e. $x$ is such that $(A + B)x = 0$), then one of the following statements must hold:

1. $Ax = 0$, which means we must also have $Bx = 0$,
2. $Ax \neq 0$, in which case we observe that $Ax = -Bx \in \operatorname{ran}(B)$.

Per the hint, consider $A|_{\ker(A + B)}$. Let $x_1,\dots,x_j$ be a basis of $\ker(A|_{\ker(A + B)}) = \ker(A) \cap \ker(B)$, and extend this to a basis, $x_1,\dots,x_k$ of $A|_{\ker(A + B)}$. The vectors $Ax_{j+1},\dots,A x_k$ form a linearly independent subset of $\operatorname{ran}(A) \cap \operatorname{ran}(B)$. Thus, it must hold that $k - j \leq \dim \operatorname{ran}(A) \cap \operatorname{ran}(B)$.

With that, we can reach the desired conclusion:
$$
\begin{align}
\dim \ker(A + B) &= k = \dim \ker(A) \cap \ker(B) + (k - j) 
\\ & \leq \dim \ker (A) \cap \ker(B) + \dim \operatorname{ran}(A) \cap \operatorname{ran}(B).
\end{align}
$$